# Segmentation Fault Trying To Simulate Double Pendulum

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm trying to make a program to simulate a double pendulum, much like [this program](http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/%7Ewheat/sdpend/solve_sdpend.c). When I run this code I get a seg fault, but I can't find what is causing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

#define PI 3.14159265 // Pi
#define G 9.8 // Acceleration due to gravity
#define L1 1.0 // Pendulum 1 Length ( meters )
#define M1 1.0 // Pendulum 1 Mass ( kilograms )
#define L2 1.0 // Pendulum 2 Length ( meters )
#define M2 1.0 // Pendulum 2 Mass ( kilograms )
#define N 4 // Number of equations. Don't change

using namespace std;

void calculateDerivatives ( vector<float> &dydx , vector<float> &yIn )
{
   // Calculate derivatives and put them in dydx vector
   dydx.clear();
   float temp1 , temp2 , delta;

   delta = yIn[2] - yIn[0];

   // Calculate sins and cosines to lower computation cost
   float sD = sin ( delta );
   float cD = cos ( delta );
   float s2D = sin ( 2 * delta );

   dydx.push_back ( yIn[1] );

   temp1 = ( M2 * L1 * pow ( yIn[1] , 2 ) * (1 / 2) * s2D );
   temp1 += ( M2 * G * sin ( yIn[2] ) * cD );
   temp1 += ( M2 * L2 * pow ( yIn[3] , 2 ) * sD );
   temp1 -= ( ( M1 + M2 ) * G * sin ( yIn[0] ) ) / ( ( M1 + M2 ) * L1 - M2 *L1 * pow ( cD , 2 ) );
   dydx.push_back ( temp1 );

   dydx.push_back ( yIn[3] );

   temp2 = ( -M2 * L2 * pow ( yIn[3] , 2 ) * ( 1 / 2 ) * s2D );
   temp2 += ( M1 + M2 ) * G * sin ( yIn[0] ) * cD;
   temp2 -= ( M1 + M2 ) * L1 * pow ( yIn[1] , 2) * sD;
   temp2 -= ( ( M1 + M2 ) * G * sin ( yIn[2] ) ) / ( ( L2 / L1 ) * delta );
   dydx.push_back ( temp2 );
}

void doRungeKutta ( const float x , const float h , vector<float> &yIn , vector<float> &yOut )
{
   // Use the Runge Kutta method to solve the DE
   vector<float> dydx;
   vector<float> dydxt;
   vector<float> yt;
   vector< vector<float> > kuttas;

   // Step 1
   calculateDerivatives ( dydx , yIn );
   vector<float> temp;
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      temp.push_back( h * dydx[i] );
      yt.push_back ( yIn[i] + ( 0.5 ) * temp[i] );
   }
   kuttas.push_back ( temp );

   // Step 2
   calculateDerivatives ( dydxt , yt );
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      temp[i] = ( h * dydxt[i] );
      yt[i] = ( yIn[i] + ( 0.5 ) * temp[i] );
   }
   kuttas.push_back ( temp );

   // Step 3
   calculateDerivatives ( dydxt , yt );
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      temp[i] = ( h * dydxt[i] );
      yt[i] = ( yIn[i] + temp[i] );
   }
   kuttas.push_back ( temp );

   // Step 4
   calculateDerivatives ( dydxt , yt );
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      temp[i] = ( h * dydxt[i] );
      yOut.push_back ( yIn[i] + kuttas[0][i] / 6.0 + kuttas[1][i] / 3.0 + kuttas[2][i] / 3.0 + kuttas[3][i] / 6.0 );
   }

}

int main( int argc , char *argv[] )
{
   int steps;
   float time_min , time_max , sTheta1 , sTheta2 , sAngVel1 , sAngVel2;
   float degRad = PI / 180;
   vector<float> yIn , yOut , times , theta1 , theta2 , angVel1 , angVel2;

   // Get command line inputs
   time_min = atof ( argv[1] );
   time_max = atof ( argv[2] );
   sTheta1 = atof ( argv[3] );
   sAngVel1 = atof ( argv[4] );
   sTheta2 = atof ( argv[5] );
   sAngVel2 = atof ( argv[6] );
   steps = atoi ( argv[7] );

   int h = ( time_max - time_min ) / ( steps - 1 );
   for ( int i = 0; i < steps; i++ )
   {
      times[i] = time_min + h * i;
   }

   theta1.push_back( sTheta1 * degRad );
   theta2.push_back( sTheta2 * degRad );
   angVel1.push_back( sAngVel1 );
   angVel2.push_back( sAngVel2 );

   cout << times[0] << " " << theta1[0] << " "
        << angVel1[0] << " " << theta2[0] << " " << angVel2[0];

   for ( int i = 0; i < ( steps - 1 ); i++ )
   {
      yIn.push_back( theta1[i] );
      yIn.push_back( angVel1[i] );
      yIn.push_back( theta2[i] );
      yIn.push_back( angVel2[i] );

      doRungeKutta ( times[i] , h , yIn , yOut );

      theta1.push_back( yOut[0] );
      angVel1.push_back( yOut[1] );
      theta2.push_back( yOut[2] );
      angVel2.push_back( yOut[3] );
      cout << times[i + 1] << " " << theta1[i + 1] << " "
           << angVel1[i + 1] << " " << theta2[i + 1] << " " << angVel2[i + 1];

   }

   return 0;
}
```

Sorry it's so long, I just have no clue what is causing it, so I couldn't shorten it to a problem piece. I've gone through the code over and over, looking for some kind of mistake I might've made when declaring  arrays or accessing something out of bounds but I cannot find my error.

Running gdb I get this:

```
$ g++ dp.cpp
$ ./a.out 0 10 90 0 90 0 1000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ gdb a.out
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run 0 10 90 0 90 0 1000
Starting program: a.out 0 10 90 0 90 0 1000

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000008001743 in doRungeKutta(float, float, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000008001743 in doRungeKutta(float, float, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&) ()
#1  0x0000000008001c8a in main ()
(gdb)
```

Which did not help me. I tried searching in the doRungeKutta function to find the problem, alas I could not find it.

EDIT: Using vectors instead of allocating memory. However, segfault still occurs with the same gdb output.

Comment: `times = ( float * ) malloc ( indices );` -- Why are you not using `std::vector<float> times;`?  There is no need for pointers or `malloc` for this line and others that look like it.  You're also using `vector` already, so it's puzzling why you aren't using it here also.

Comment: Probably your error is due to you using `malloc` incorrectly.  The `malloc` function allocates the number of *bytes*, not the number of `float`'s.  This is one huge reason to use `std::vector<float>`, and drop the usage of `C` functions such as `malloc`.

Comment: Yes, that could be the case. However, I know that it allocates bytes, which is why I used steps * sizeof(float). I edited the code to use vectors, just in case.

Comment: *but I can't find what is causing it* -- `yOut.push_back(yIn[i] + kuttas[0][i] / 6.0 + kuttas[1][i] / 3.0 + kuttas[2][i] / 3.0 + kuttas[3][i] / 6.0)` -- How many `kuttas` are there?  .Output `kutta.size()`.  You will see that there are not 4 of them.  Also, if you replaced `[ ]` with `at()`, you would then get an `std::out_of_range` error instead of a seg fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error is here:

```
void doRungeKutta ( const float x , const float h , vector<float> &yIn , vector<float> &yOut )
{
   //...
   vector< vector<float> > kuttas;

   // Step 1
   calculateDerivatives ( dydx , yIn );
   //...
   kuttas.push_back ( temp );  // Here is the first one

   // Step 2
   calculateDerivatives ( dydxt , yt );
   //.. 
   kuttas.push_back ( temp );  // Here is the second one

   // Step 3
   calculateDerivatives ( dydxt , yt );
   //...   
   kuttas.push_back ( temp ); // Here is the third one

   // Step 4
   calculateDerivatives ( dydxt , yt );
   for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
      temp[i] = ( h * dydxt[i] );
      yOut.push_back ( yIn[i] + kuttas[0][i] / 6.0 + kuttas[1][i] / 3.0 + kuttas[2][i] 
                  / 3.0 + kuttas[3][i] / 6.0 );  // <-- Error -- there is no kutta[3]
   }
}
```

The `kuttas` vector has size 3, but you are trying to access `kutta[3]`, which is an out-of-bounds access.  Thus a memory overwrite and undefined behavior.

You also have other errors, such as some of those `vector` items having `-inf` values, but the obvious error is the one pointed out.